i set up a port forwarding on port 50070 to access the hadoop master node
$ ssh -i C:/Users/amyousufi/Desktop/private-key -L 50070:localhost:50070 ubuntu@14.10.201.50
after set up my port, i recieve the following error:
bind [127.0.0.1]:50070: Permission denied
channel_setup_fwd_listener_tcpip: cannot listen to port: 50070
i want to login to the hadoop master using my windows and send some data from desktop.

You don't need SSH Proxy to setup the or use hdfs CLI commands. Also, this won't work since you'd also need to connect to the data node ports, not just the namenode

thank you for your response but i still need the namenode port to send data. i use this hdfs cli command:

curl -i -L -X PUT "http://localhost:50070/webhdfs/v1/user/root/alert.csv?op=CREATE&overwrite=true" -H "Content-Type: application/octet-stream" -T "C:\Users\amyousufi\Desktop\alert.csv"

That is curl, which is different from hdfs put command.
